# Returning element of a vector of a pure virtual base class

Tags: c++, oop, vector, pure-virtual

I have a virtual class Animal, and I want to store Animal objects in a vector and be able to access any Animal object in this vector by index.

I declared my vector: `std::vector <Animal*> anim;`

Am able to add to my vector using:

```
void Shelter::add_animal(Animal& animal){
    anim.push_back(&animal);
}
```

But when I try to access my animals using:

```
Animal& Shelter::animal(int index){
    return anim[index];
}
```

I run into an error.

```
shelter.cpp:18:28: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Animal&’ from expression of type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<Animal*> >::value_type {aka Animal*}’
     return _anim[index];
```

I'd like to understand why I can't access this vector the same way I've accessed vectors in the past. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing pointers to Animals, and not Animals. dereference the pointer.

```cpp
Animal& Shelter::animal(int index){
    return *anim[index];
}
```

/edit

My original suggestion was incorrect, but this is why I made that suggestion....

You might want to consider changing the interface for:

```cpp
void Shelter::add_animal(Animal& animal);
```

This pretty much guarantees a maintenance nightmare. It implies I can do:

```cpp
void makePig(Shelter& s)
{
  Pig littlePiggy;
  s.add_animal(littlePiggy);
}
```

Which is how I originally thought the code would be used (hence my parsing error when answering the question). Personally speaking, I'd argue this would be better:

```cpp
void Shelter::add_animal(Animal* animal);
```

The simple reason being that with this interface, all compilers will spit out a warning if you do this:

```cpp
  Pig littlePiggy;
  s.add_animal(&littlePiggy); //< Warning! taking address of temp var.
```

With the original interface, no such warning will ever be generated, and the interface implies that you will be copying data into it (rather than storing a pointer to some var)

Comment: `std::vector <Animal>` will not work, for the very obvious reasons.

Comment: I agree that ```std::vector <Animal>``` wouldn't work, but I'm very appreciative of robthebloke pointing out that I had to dereference.

Comment: updated my answer to explain why I made that suggestion. It's *not* a great interface for what the Shelter object is actually doing.

Comment: The key concern here is deciding if a `Shelter` contains and manages a set of `Animal`s (e.g. when the shelter ceases to exist, all the animals do too) or if the `Shelter` is simply associated with a set of animals  (e.g. if the `Shelter` is demolished, do the animals continue to exist).    Personally, I would not have a `Shelter::add_animal()` function at all.   Instead, I'd give `Animal` a `Use(Shelter &)` function, which allows an animal to associate itself with and use a shelter, but not actually be a part of that shelter.